# Is it possible to write a MySQL query that deletes records using identifying values in a CSV?

Tags: mysql, csv

I know how to do the following in PHP, but I am wondering if it is possible to write a "pure" MySQL query to do the same:

Every night, I have a script which generates a CSV file of primary key IDs that I need to delete from a large database of records.

Is it possible to write a MySQL query that reads the CSV file, and deletes the record for each primary key value?   In psuedocode, something along the lines of:

```
   READ 'CSVFILE.csv' AS FILE;
   FOR EACH( VALUE IN FILE )
        DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id = VALUE;
```

Is something like this even possible just using a MySQL query?

Comment: So your question is not PHP related at all?

Comment: i dont belive you can basically upload a csv file to a query, id do it with php, read the file and gather ID-s that will be used

Comment: @mitkosoft Correct...I'm asking if it is possible to do what I'm asking just with a MySQL query.  I already know how to do it in PHP.

Comment: @Yves, `LOAD DATA INFILE` is possible solution in order to load CSV data into a table and then to perform `DELETE`. However this cannot be done with single query, `STORED PROCEDURE` is the way, so check here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: @mitkosoft Thanks...I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your job by using two queries and making a temporary table.
[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'CSVFILE.csv' INTO TABLE temp_tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id IN (SELECT toDeleteIdColumn FROM temp_tbl_name);
```

Comment: This makes sense.  Thanks.